# Farseer Physics Engine and XNA 4

Tags: xna, farseer, physics-engine

Anybody did compile Farseer Physics Engine 3.0 with XNA 4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [release page](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/27942):

> This release does not support XNA 4.0. XNA 4.0 introduced some breaking changes that means you will have to change some files in order for the release to compile. The current version (FPE 3.1) in the source control does support XNA 4.0.

You can download the latest source from http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets - although it may not be as nicely packaged as the release. It also may not be as stable.

Of course - I imagine that you probably *can* use Farseer 3.0 on XNA 4.0, because as far as I know there are no breaking changes in the maths-related classes between XNA 3.1 and XNA 4.0. You just won't be able to compile the demos (unless you fiddle with them).

Comment: it is interesting that Farseer Physics Engine 2 supports XNA 4

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is correct. Everything is upgraded in the latest source, however only the rendering part of the samples and testbed need to be modified for the release version to work in 4.0. The engine itself has to dependencies on any specific version of Xna and even includes a Vanilla version for use without Xna.